# Morris Chart is not displaying page is blank

Tags: php, html, charts, display

This is my simple code to fetch data from mysql and then import the data value to morrisjs but my page is pure blank showing nothing. I am new to this

```
<?php
        
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userchart");
    $query= "SELECT * FROM chart";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $chart_data='';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $time= strtotime($row['time']);
        
        $chart_data .="{ user:'".$row['uid']."', time:".date('i',$time)."}";
    }
       

    echo $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -1);
?>
```

I used this statement for testing if I am getting value in correct format and the format is correct but at the end the line chart is not showing.

```
echo $chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -1);

<html>
    <head>
        <title> CHART USING MORRIS.JS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="chart" style ="height 250px;"></div>

        <script>
            new Morris.Line({
                // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
                element: 'chart',
                // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
                // the chart.
                data: [<?php echo $chart_data; ?>], 

                // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
                xkey: 'user',
                // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
                ykeys: ['time'],
                // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
                // chart.
                labels: ['time']
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SCREAMING AT US? And you should use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create the json instead of doing it manually. If the database returns more than one record, your current code will generate invalid json. If you have multiple objects in an array, they need to be comma separated: `[{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, ...]`

Comment: why try to reinvent the wheel and construct your own JSON data string? Use `json_encode` - it will be consistent and reliable

Comment: What have you tried to check for problems? Does the generated markup look like the markup you expect? Is there any error message shown in your browser's error console?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, the console was showing some syntax error, now its working fine thanks for the help.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry for that Sir. Ok sir, I will try to use JSON encode(). But I dont know nothing about json any suggestion from where I should began with. Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but perhaps you might try like this. Rather than doing some flaky string manipulation you ought to use `json_encode`

```
<?php
        
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userchart");
    $query= "SELECT * FROM chart";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    
    $data=array();
    
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $data[]=array(
            'user'  =>  $row['uid'],
            'time'  =>  date('i',strtotime( $row['time']) )
        );
    }
    $json=json_encode( $data );
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CHART USING MORRIS.JS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="chart" style ="height 250px;"></div>

        <script>
            <?php
            printf('var json=%s;',$json);
            ?>
            new Morris.Line({
                element: 'chart',
                data:json,
                xkey:'user',
                ykeys:['time'],
                labels:['time']
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate this is working I don't know why but yes its working fine.